# Can I use class attribute with same value in many posts of blogger?

Tags: html, css

Can I use class attribute with same value in many posts of blogger.

Example like:

**In Blogger post**

```
<div class="panel-heading body-1">some content</div>
<div class="panel-heading body-2">some content</div>
<div class="panel-heading body-3">some content</div>
<div class="panel-heading body-4">some content</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what classes are for, to be used many times to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is as clear as I can be with the given information, but if the elements are all inside the same document, there shouldn't be a problem.

It would help if you could explain what you mean by 'blogger' and 'blogger template' so I can improve my answer.